# Comparar que distintos datos de una matriz asociativa son iguales o no, PHP, datos de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El caso que tengo dos tablas de MySQL (pedidos_remoto y pedidos) y quiero compararlas para ver que datos de una he de actualizar en la otra de forma automática.
Por el momento, te saco un array asociativo con los datos de cada tabla. Los elementos de dicho array tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
array(9272) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["IdPedido"]=>
    string(9) " 3424324-A"
    ["numeroseguimiento"]=>
    string(8) "3454365-A"
    ["Estado"]=>
    NULL
    ["cod_pedido_prov"]=>
    NULL
    ["agencia_prov"]=>
    NULL
    ["url_tracking"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Y el código que hago para comparar los arrays con todos los datos de cada tabla es el siguiente:

```
function comprobarCambiosPedidosEnPedidosRemoto($datosPedidos, $datosPedidosRemoto){
    
            //Creo un array para tener los datos que difieren entre ambas tablas
            $registrosDiferentes = [];

            // Recorrer arreglo de resultados Pedidos
            foreach($datosPedidos as $idPedido) {
            // Si el pedido existe en pedidos_remoto
                if(isset($datosPedidosRemoto[$idPedido])) {
                    //NO SÉ COMO COGERLE LOS 5 CAMPOS PARA COMPARARLOS
                } 
            }
        
            // var_dump($registrosDiferentes);
            return $registrosDiferentes;
}
```

Básicamente quiero que me recorra el array con los $datosPedidos, y cuando dicho ID Pedido exista en PedidosRemoto (no sé si el código está bien o no), quiero que me coja los 5-6 campos que tiene ese array de la matriz, y me los compare uno a uno, con los datos de pedidos_remoto correspondientes. Y que me guarde esa info en un array ($registrosDiferentes).

Como no sé si me he explicado bien, voy a poner un ejemplo de lo que quiero para que se entienda mejor. En el IdPedido "000000-C" de la tabla pedidos, ha habido un cambio en el Estado y ahora dicho campo tiene un valor de "Problemas en la entrega del producto". La estructura de este array es:

```
array(6) {
    ["IdPedido"]=>
    string(9) " 000000-C"
    ["numeroseguimiento"]=>
    string(8) "dsada-x"
    ["Estado"]=>
    "Problemas en la entrega del producto"
    ["cod_pedido_prov"]=>
    NULL
    ["agencia_prov"]=>
    "Madrid"
    ["url_tracking"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Entonces, entiendo que el código debería hacer lo siguiente:

1. Comprobar que dicho IDPedido existe en la matriz datosPedidosRemoto.
2. Si existe, buscar el array dentro de la matriz con el mismo IdPedido.
3. Cuando lo encuentre, comparar campo a campo.
4. Si la comparación resulta true (es decir, que todos los campos son exactamente iguales) no hacemos nada. Si resulta false, como en este caso, dónde en la tabla pedidos el campo Estado tiene el valor "Problemas en la entrega del producto" y en la tabla pedidos_remoto el campo Estado para este registro tiene el valor "En Proceso", tendría que guardar todos los datos de este array (el de $datosPedidos) en $registrosDiferentes, para con otra función ya proceder a hacer el update en la tabla pedidos_remoto.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo implementar esto? La idea la tengo más o menos clara pero a la hora de pasarlo a código, me está costando. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: `$datosPedidosRemoto["numeroseguimiento"]` ó `$datosPedidosRemoto["IdPedido"] `coge ese valor en concreto, despues solo tienes que usar condicionales para evaluar y ya.

Comment: no te valdria con un `array_diff_assoc` ?

Comment: Entiendo que no porque estoy trabajando con una matriz. Y tampoco me sirve que me devuelva los datos diferentes sueltos, necesitaría que me devolviera el array específico en concreto.